# Add extra custom resource table in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'd like to add a new custom array "resource" in FullCalendar to group CITIES information instead insert cities elements (name, latitude, longitude, ...) directly inside events array (to prevent to much data loading...).

To retrieve a resource exist a specific function:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getEventResource', event.id );
```

But how can I get my custom array "customArrayCities" from "cityID" inside my events? Is it possible?

```
customArrayCities: [
  { id: 'C1', name: 'New York', latitude: '44.111111', longitude: '10.111111'},
  { id: 'C2', name: 'Houston', latitude: '45.111111', longitude: '11.111111'}             
]
resources: [
  { id: 'a', impianti: 'Impianto 1', title: 'Linea 1' },
  { id: 'b', impianti: 'Impianto 2', title: 'Linea 2' }
],
events: [
  { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T02:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', title: 'Title 1', cityID: 'C1'},
  { id: '2', resourceId: 'b', start: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', title: 'Title 2', cityID: 'C1' }
]
```

For example i need a snippet like:

```
var array_cities = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getCustomArrayCitiesByEventID', event.id );
```

For example with event.id = 1

```
for (i in array_cities) {
  echo array_cities[i].id;
  echo array_cities[i].name;
}
```

Output:

```
C1
New York
```

I need it when I click on a Event. I get a Bootstrap Modal with info about event and further info about city.

Comment: Your wording is not very clear. Are you saying you want to make a restriction so that you only fetch events from the server for a particular city, or cities, based on the contents of `customArrayCities`? Or does each resource associate with a particular city? Like I said, it really isn't very clear what you mean. Perhaps an example of input and desired output would help?

Comment: I've added an example what i need

Comment: if you just want to extract some information from the current event list, and filter it, you can use the clientEvents function (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) to get the event you're interested in, and it looks like you already have an idea how you can loop through the cities array - this cities array doesn't need to be integrated into fullCalendar, as far as I can see, unless I have misunderstood your purpose.

Comment: Yes i know I can insert all info about a city directly inside a event....but if I'll have a big numbers of events with the same city, i get a lot of data to load. In example above i've added only 3 or 4 element for the city...but if I have 20 elements for a city and I have 1000 events with the same city, there's a big redondancy of data replicated inside events...

Comment: I didn't say you needed to do that. You only need the city ID within the event. Then you can place your array somewhere on the page, and use that to relate it to the event and display the city info. To clarify further, at what time in the process are you hoping to do this? You want to use this to change the display of the events when they are loading? Or at some other time?

Comment: Ok. I need it when I click on a Event. I get a Bootstrap Modal with info about event and further info about city...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having clarified (from the comments) that you want to do this when the event is clicked, here is a simplified example. It does not use Scheduler, or a bootstrap modal, but it gives you the general principle, and you can adapt it easily to add those details.

```
var cities = [{
  id: 'C1',
  name: 'New York',
  latitude: '44.111111',
  longitude: '10.111111'
}, {
  id: 'C2',
  name: 'Houston',
  latitude: '45.111111',
  longitude: '11.111111'
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    defaultDate: "2017-09-07",
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: [{
      id: '1',
      resourceId: 'a',
      start: '2017-09-07T02:00:00',
      end: '2017-09-07T04:00:00',
      title: 'Title 1',
      cityID: 'C1'
    }, {
      id: '2',
      resourceId: 'b',
      start: '2017-09-07T04:00:00',
      end: '2017-09-07T13:00:00',
      title: 'Title 2',
      cityID: 'C1'
    }, {
      id: '3',
      resourceId: 'b',
      start: '2017-09-10T04:00:00',
      end: '2017-09-10T13:00:00',
      title: 'Title 3',
      cityID: 'C2'
    }],
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      //loop through the cities until we find the right one
      $.each(cities, function(index, city) {
        if (city.id == calEvent.cityID)
        {
          //display the city information however you wish to:
          alert("City: " + city.name);
          return false; //stop looping now we've found the correct record
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/31/ for a working example.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!